# Facebook Connect Using C# ASP.net

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0

Hi i want to develop an Facebook Connect application on my Website using C#.net which will retrieve all my Friends Birthday List from my Facebook account & post it on my Website.

Similar to what www.gifts.com is having. Request anyone to share a Sample Code or any idea for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the  [Facebook c# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) it should be able to get you going in the right direction. It is available via [NuGet](http://nuget.org) if you are using Visual Studio.